# How to start timer with open ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I want to create a timer, which goes on while i switch to an another ViewController and come back later. My solution is this way:

1. I start the timer with an button
2. then i hand over the integer to the next ViewController
3. I start the timer with the new integer

So my problem results in step three: I want to start the timer in the function `viewDidLoad()`. But the timer doesn't starts in the next ViewController.

i hope anybody can help me. Tell me, if there is a better way to do the things i want.

Here is my Code:

```
var timer = Timer()
var eighthours: Int = 8
var activejob: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    identify_activejob()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(Jobs.jobtime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

//functions
@objc func jobtime() {
    eighthours -= 1
}
```

Comment: In the first ViewController i want to start the timer. And in the second i want to show the time. I thought that i have to start another timer to simulate the timer process. But i think this is the wrong way. I only want that the timer goes on if i change the ViewController. And i want to show the time in another viewcontroller.

Comment: How about a global timer?

Comment: @E.Coms how can i use a global timer?

Comment: set a timer out of any class. Or use a static var timer: Timer. Then call UIControllerView.timer to  set a global Timer.

Comment: Any time you find yourself reaching for a “global” (or “singleton” or “put it in the app delegate” or anything that is globally accessible), that’s a red flag that you need to stop and think whether that is the right approach. It’s not that these don’t have their uses, but nine times out of ten, it’s not. IMHO, this is not one of those cases.

Comment: @E.Coms can you show me an example code how to create a global timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show you one way. But may as suggested, it has native design flaw and use it depends on the accuracy.

```
   let timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
let string = ISO8601DateFormatter().string(from: Date())
 print("running" + string)
     }
   }
    class TimerViewController: UIViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     }
  }
```

It will keep running until invalidate.

Comment: Thanks. But where can i define the time for the timer?

Comment: I want that the timer count down a time i give him

Comment: you can calculate the time difference. Then set the timer interval.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: how can in calculate the time difference?

Comment: “It will keep running until invalidate.” ... It also won’t release the view controller until you `invalidate`, too.

Comment: Use date object function to calculate the time difference

Answer (score 2):

A couple of thoughts:

- The `eighthours -= 1` in the timer handler is slightly problematic, because it’s presuming that the `Timer` will fire, without interruption, at the desired `timeInterval`. But you should accommodate for interruptions in the `Timer` (e.g. the UI is blocked momentarily for some reason, the user completely leaves the app and returns, etc.).

  We often shift from “decrement some counter with every call of the timer handler” to “figure out at what time we want the timer to expire”. This decouples the “model” (the stop time) from the “view” (the frequency with which the UI is updated). By doing this, if you later decide to update your UI with greater frequency (e.g showing milliseconds rather than seconds, probably using `CADisplayLink` instead of `Timer`), it doesn’t change the model driving the app. And it makes your app invulnerable to momentary interruptions that might affect the timer.

  If you adopt this pattern, then you can pass around this “stop time”, your model, from view controller to view controller, and each view controller can start and stop its own timer as required by the desired UX for that scene.

  So, to start a timer that will stop in 8 seconds:

  ```
  var stopTime: Date?   // set this when you start the timer

  func startTimer() {
      stopTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(8)

      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(jobtime(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }
  ```

  And the timer handler can determine how much time is left with `timeIntervalSince` to calculate the floating point difference, in seconds, between two dates.

  ```
  @objc func jobtime(_ timer: Timer) {
      let now = Date()

      guard let stopTime = stopTime, now < stopTime else {
          timer.invalidate()
          return
      }

      let timeRemaining = stopTime.timeIntervalSince(now)

      ...
  }
  ```

  I also updated `jobtime` with a `timer` parameter so that you can see at a glance that it’s a `Timer` handler.
- FYI, your code introduces a strong reference to the view controller that will prevent it from ever being released. This selector-based `Timer` keeps a strong reference to its target and the run loop keeps a reference to the `Timer`, so your view controller won’t be released until you [`invalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate) the `Timer`.

  There are a couple of solutions to this:

  - Start and stop timers as views appear and disappear:

    ```
    weak var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(jobtime(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func jobtime(_ timer: Timer) { ... }
    ```

    Note, we’re doing this in `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` (rather than `viewDidLoad`) to ensure that the starting and stopping of timers is always balanced.
  - The other pattern is to use block-based `Timer`, use `[weak self]` reference to avoid having timer keeping strong reference to the view controller, and then you can `invalidate` it in the `deinit` method:

    ```
    weak var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            self?.jobtime(timer)
        }
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
    ```
  - Finally, if you want to update the UI with the greatest possible frequency (e.g. to show milliseconds), you’d probably use a `CADisplayLink` which is a special timer, perfectly timed for UI updates:

    ```
    private weak var displayLink: CADisplayLink?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(jobtime(_:)))
        displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
        self.displayLink = displayLink
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        displayLink?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func jobtime(_ displayLink: CADisplayLink) { ... }
    ```

  But the common feature in all of these approaches is that (a) we eliminate strong references from persisting that will interfere with the view controller from getting deallocated when appropriate; and (b) we let every view controller update its UI with whatever frequency it wants.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your big answer. But I only want a global timer. Is there any way to set a timer global?

Comment: I think that’s a bad idea, for the reasons I discuss above, but you’d create a global like any other global. The interesting question, though, is how you would have each view controller then subscribe/observe to that timer (because presumably you want both view controllers to reflect the ticking of your timer). I can imagine a few clumsy ways to do that (give your timer manager some closure that it should call; use `NotificationCenter`, etc.). But I wonder why you’d want to go through all of that...

Comment: Where in your code is the part which shows me how to use the timer in other ViewControllers?

Comment: I’m suggesting that you might not want to pass a timer around at all. I’m suggesting that you might just pass around the “model”, e.g. what you’re counting down to, and then each view controller starts its own timer to update your UI with whatever frequency you want.

Comment: Oh okay. I found a solution but thank you for your answer.